# Why is the last chapter in masechet pesachim called ערבי פסחים in the plural, which does not match the girsa of the mishnah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, writing-printing, maseches-pesachim

The mishnah begins ערב פסחים in the singular, yet the chapter is called ערבי פסחים in the plural. Chapter titles in the gemara almost always match the first words verbatim, very rarely skipping a word or two. But I can't think of any other prakim where the chapter name doesn't match the text. Apparently there was a girsa that read ערבי פסחים (see first Tosafot there), but why would the heading and text reflect different girsaot?

Comment: Lol, was this question sparked by my question about why the last chapter in senhedrin isn’t called kol israel?

Comment: See first tosafot

Comment: @AvishaiTebeka yes I was going to ask this as an irrelevant comment and then decided this would be more appropriate.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think Tosafot are addressing this question. I think their main issue is that it doesn't' seem to make sense for the *mishnah* to say erev (singular) pesachim (plural). And they answer that Q. However, I overlooked that they do say b'ferush there is a girsa "Arvei" so I am modifying that part of the Q.

Comment: If anything, Erev is the anomaly. Mishnayos has it as Arvei, and the gemara quotes it that way too.